# How to fix method in python that returns a 2d array with empty array elements?

Tags: python, arrays

The following code implements a backtracking algorithm to find all the possible permutations of a given array of numbers and the record variable stores the permutation when the code reaches base case. The code seems to run accordingly, that is, the record variable gets filled up with valid permutations, but for some reason when the method finishes the method returns a two-dimensional array whose elements are empty.

I tried declaring `record` as a tuple or a dictionary and tried using global and nonlocal variables, but it none of it worked.

```
def permute(arr):
    record = []
    def createPermutations(currentArr, optionArr):
        if len(optionArr) == 0:
            if len(currentArr) != 0: record.append(currentArr)
            else: pass
            print(record)
        else:
            for num in range(len(optionArr)):
                currentArr.append(optionArr[num])
                option = optionArr[0:num] + optionArr[num+1::]
                createPermutations(currentArr, option)
                currentArr.pop()

    createPermutations([], arr)
    return record

print(permute([1,2,3]))
```

The expect result should be [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]], but instead I got [[], [], [], [], [], []].

Comment: If you are trying to find all permutations, are you sure that [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]] is a valid result?

Comment: Your right! I probably copied the wrong output after I made changes to my code. But, let's just ignore that.

Comment: John Coleman's answer will fix your code so you should accept it, but look at mine to understand why it was happening.

Answer (score 3):

With recursive functions, you should pass a *copy* of the current array, rather than having all of those `currentArr.pop()` mutating the same array.

Replace

```
createPermutations(currentArr, option)
```

by

```
createPermutations(currentArr[:], option)
```

Finally, as a learning exercise for recursion, something like this is fine, but if you need permutations for a practical programming problem, use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html):

```
print([list(p) for p in itertools.permutations([1,2,3])])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would accept John Coleman's answer as it is the correct way to solve your issue and resolves other bugs that you run into as a result.

The reason you run into this issue because python is pass-by-object-reference, in which copies of lists are not passed in but the actual list itself. What this leads to is another issue in your code; in which you would get `[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]` as your output when you `print(record)`.

Why this happens is that when you call `record.append(currentArr)`, it actually points to the same object reference as all the other times you call `record.append(currentArr)`. Thus you will end up with 6 copies of the same array (in this case `currentArr`) at the end because all your appends point to the same array. A 2d list is just a list of pointers to other lists.

Now that you understand this, it is easier to understand why you get `[[],[],[],[],[],[]]` as your final output. Because you add to and then pop from `currentArr` over here `currentArr.append(optionArr[num])`
and over here
`currentArr.pop()` to return it back to normal, 
your final version of `currentArr` will be what you passed in, i.e. `[]`.
Since `result` is a 2d array of 6 `currentArr`s, you will get `[[],[],[],[],[],[]]` as your returned value.

This may help you better how it all works, since it has diagrams as well: https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/